# C# reading XML 5 level deep

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read sintal id A and Sylvia

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<kdd>
    <Table>
        <robel ID="1">
            <groof NAME="GOBS-1">
                <sintal ID="A">Sylvia</sintal>
            </groof>
        </robel>
    </Table>
</kdd>
```

I have tried below and it didnt work. The value for element is null, and after that it exits out.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("myname.xml");
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("sintal"))
{
     string my_id = element.Attribute("sintal").Value;
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: You should be able to just use the XPath for the element. (no need to loop if you know the document structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Attribute name is `ID` not `sintal`, `sintal` is your *element* name. Try this:

```
 string my_id = (string)element.Attribute("ID");
 string myValue = (string)element;
```

Also use *explicit cast* instead of `Value` property to get the value of the element or attribute.It avoids the `NullReferenceException`.